# Prove that a set is not strictly convex

Tags: convex-analysis, approximation-theory

> I want to prove that the set $\{ f:||f||_{\infty}=1 \}$ where $f$ belongs to the space of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ is not a strictly convex set. As a counterexample, I'm asked to use $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$ on $[0,1]$

I do understand the definition of convex set and strict convex set, but apparently not enough to prove this fact. I tried by contradiction, assuming it's convex in hope to find an element that is not an interior of the set. But I don't seem to get anywhere, so any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you supposed to show that the set is not convex, or not strictly convex?

Comment: @saulspatz which $t$ might that be?

Comment: I think I'd rather show that all proper convex combinations of $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=1-x$ are not in the set

Comment: I would use $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=1-x$, and $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Corrected it, prove that it's not STRICTLY convex

Comment: I mean, clearly the set is convex, right?

Comment: @saulspatz: The maximum of $tx^2+(1-t)x$ on $[0,1]$ is always $1$ at $x=1$ if $t\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @Sam See the comments by carmichael561 and me - the set is far from convex

Comment: @carmichael561 You're right of course. I just assumed the given counterexample would work.  But both functions are increasing, so any convex combination of them will be increasing -- I should have noticed that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. As the question was asked, it was obvious to me that it was convex but not strictly convex. I made an answer via your examples, I hope it is correct

Comment: How do you define "strictly convex"?

Comment: Edited in my answer

Answer (score 1):

A set $S$ is called strictly convex if it is convex and furthermore all points $\lambda f + (1 - \lambda)g $ $\lambda \in (0,1)$ are in the interior of the set, for all $f,g \in S$.

The set can't be strictly convex because it is not even convex. As an example, pick $f(x)=x, g(x)=1-x$ on $[0,1]$ and $\lambda=1/2$. Clearly $f$ and $g$ belongs to the set. But $||\lambda g +(1-\lambda)f||_{\infty}= ||(1-x)/2+x/2||_{\infty}=1/2$, which shows that $\lambda g +(1-\lambda)f$ is not in the space, so can't be convex by definition.

Comment: Maybe he wants the full ball?

Comment: Edited the answer, this is the definition given by my professor. Is there different definitions? If so that's just confusing don't you think?

Comment: ok i get what you mean now. My professor had made a mistake in the question and it should be the whole unit ball...

Answer (score 0):

Take $f = 1$ and $g = -1$ then $h = 0$ which is obviously the convex combination of $f$ and $g$ does not to  belong the Unite sphere.